# app crashes on redmi phone - ZygoteInit$Method nullpointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, redmi-device

Android app that I have developed crashes frequently mainly on Redmi phone. Android version 6.0. App crashes at any time with the same error/similar error.

Please help with below error, unable to get why this error is coming every now and then.
This is the error stack -

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: in.test.coupon, PID: 27695
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{in.test.coupon/in.test.coupon.activities.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.res.Resources
>   android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>                                                                              at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
>                                                                              at
>   android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:549)
>                                                                              at android.view.Window.getDefaultFeatures(Window.java:1359)
>                                                                              at android.view.Window.(Window.java:480)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.(PhoneWindow.java:305)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.policy.MiuiPhoneWindow.(MiuiPhoneWindow.java:10)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:6243)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)

Comment: please post your code...

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: I realized the issue is coming due to these lines of code -   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
on loading one of the fragment. If I comment this code, I get same error on this fragment load.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to launch activity `in.test.coupon/in.test.coupon.activities.MainActivity` from some background thread/task, which keeps running even after your activity is destroyed.

Please make sure to stop all such tasks/ threads in your activity `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: How do I know what threads are running in background. In main activity all are sequential calls. The stack trace doesn't give clear information.